# GKE OFBiz pod not connecting to Google Cloud SQL database

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ofbiz

Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/appliedcode/mail-server-ofbiz-with-mysql-setup-f5e64bade787) to connect OFBiz to a MySQL database.

I'm trying to create an OFBiz deployment with persistent storage where new pods will store and retrieve data from MySQL.

**Dockerfile for OFBiz pods**

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y gradle unzip wget vim

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/ofbiz/apache-ofbiz-17.12.05.zip && \
unzip apache-ofbiz-17.12.05

WORKDIR apache-ofbiz-17.12.05

RUN gradle wrapper && \
./gradlew cleanAll loadAll

# Allowing URL $URL
RUN sed -i -e 's/host-headers-allowed=/host-headers-allowed=$URL,/g' /apache-ofbiz-17.12.05/framework/security/config/security.properties

COPY entityengine.xml /apache-ofbiz-17.12.05/framework/entity/config/

CMD ["/apache-ofbiz-17.12.05/gradlew", "ofbiz"]
```

I am hosting everything on GCP with OFBiz inside a pod running on GKE and am using Google Cloud SQL as a managed MySQL service. I have Cloud SQL set up with a public IP at 34.75.32.160.

**Preliminary SQL Commands**
I ran the following commands on my database before starting OFBiz.

```sql
create database ofbiz;  
create database ofbizolap;  
create database ofbiztenant;  
use mysql;  
select database();  
create user ofbiz@localhost;  
create user ofbizolap@localhost;  
create user ofbiztenant@localhost;  
update user set password=PASSWORD("FAKEPASSWORD") where User='ofbiz';  
update user set password=PASSWORD("FAKEPASSWORD") where User='ofbizolap';  
update user set password=PASSWORD("FAKEPASSWORD") where User='ofbiztenant';  
grant all privileges on *.* to 'ofbiz'@localhost identified by 'ofbiz';  
grant all privileges on *.* to 'ofbizolap'@localhost identified by 'ofbizolap';  
grant all privileges on *.* to 'ofbiztenant'@localhost identified by 'ofbiztenant';
```

**OFBiz Configuration with `entityengine.xml`**
The data backend for ofbiz is configured inside a file `entityengine.xml` which I have configured in the following way:

**Data Source Declarations**
I declared three different datasources `localmysql`, `localmysqlolap`, and `localmysqltenant` each connecting to my Cloud SQL server with JDBC.

```xml
<datasource name="localmysql"
            helper-class="org.apache.ofbiz.entity.datasource.GenericHelperDAO"
            field-type-name="mysql"
            check-on-start="true"
            add-missing-on-start="true"
            check-pks-on-start="false"
            use-foreign-keys="true"
            join-style="ansi-no-parenthesis"
            alias-view-columns="false"
            drop-fk-use-foreign-key-keyword="true"
            table-type="InnoDB"
            character-set="utf8"
            collate="utf8_general_ci">
        <read-data reader-name="tenant"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed-initial"/>
        <read-data reader-name="demo"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-test"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-demo"/>
        <inline-jdbc
                jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://34.75.32.160/ofbiz?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                jdbc-username="ofbiz"
                jdbc-password="<password>"
                isolation-level="ReadCommitted"
                pool-minsize="2"
                pool-maxsize="250"
                time-between-eviction-runs-millis="600000"/><!-- Please note that at least one person has experienced a problem with this value with MySQL
                and had to set it to -1 in order to avoid this issue.
                For more look at http://markmail.org/thread/5sivpykv7xkl66px and http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html-->
        <!-- <jndi-jdbc jndi-server-name="localjndi" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDataSource" isolation-level="Serializable"/> -->
    </datasource>
    <datasource name="localmysqlolap"
            helper-class="org.apache.ofbiz.entity.datasource.GenericHelperDAO"
            field-type-name="mysql"
            check-on-start="true"
            add-missing-on-start="true"
            check-pks-on-start="false"
            use-foreign-keys="true"
            join-style="ansi-no-parenthesis"
            alias-view-columns="false"
            drop-fk-use-foreign-key-keyword="true"
            table-type="InnoDB"
            character-set="utf8"
            collate="utf8_general_ci">
        <read-data reader-name="tenant"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed-initial"/>
        <read-data reader-name="demo"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-test"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-demo"/>
        <inline-jdbc
                jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://34.75.32.160/ofbizolap?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                jdbc-username="ofbizolap"
                jdbc-password="<password>"
                isolation-level="ReadCommitted"
                pool-minsize="2"
                pool-maxsize="250"
                time-between-eviction-runs-millis="600000"/><!-- Please note that at least one person has experienced a problem with this value with MySQL
                and had to set it to -1 in order to avoid this issue.
                For more look at http://markmail.org/thread/5sivpykv7xkl66px and http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html-->
        <!-- <jndi-jdbc jndi-server-name="localjndi" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDataSource" isolation-level="Serializable"/> -->
    </datasource>
    <datasource name="localmysqltenant"
            helper-class="org.apache.ofbiz.entity.datasource.GenericHelperDAO"
            field-type-name="mysql"
            check-on-start="true"
            add-missing-on-start="true"
            check-pks-on-start="false"
            use-foreign-keys="true"
            join-style="ansi-no-parenthesis"
            alias-view-columns="false"
            drop-fk-use-foreign-key-keyword="true"
            table-type="InnoDB"
            character-set="utf8"
            collate="utf8_general_ci">
        <read-data reader-name="tenant"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed"/>
        <read-data reader-name="seed-initial"/>
        <read-data reader-name="demo"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-test"/>
        <read-data reader-name="ext-demo"/>
        <inline-jdbc
                jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://34.75.32.160/ofbiztenant?autoReconnect=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                jdbc-username="ofbiztenant"
                jdbc-password="<password>"
                isolation-level="ReadCommitted"
                pool-minsize="2"
                pool-maxsize="250"
                time-between-eviction-runs-millis="600000"/><!-- Please note that at least one person has experienced a problem with this value with MySQL
                and had to set it to -1 in order to avoid this issue.
                For more look at http://markmail.org/thread/5sivpykv7xkl66px and http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html-->
        <!-- <jndi-jdbc jndi-server-name="localjndi" jndi-name="java:/MySqlDataSource" isolation-level="Serializable"/> -->
    </datasource>
```

**Delegators**
The delegators tell OFBiz which datasource to use for which functions (in this case: the functions are normal, olap, and tenant).
There is one entry for the different ways we can run OFBiz: `default`, `default-no-eca`, and `test`.

I have it set up here to use the MySQL data sources I defined above.

```xml
    <delegator name="default" entity-model-reader="main" entity-group-reader="main" entity-eca-reader="main" distributed-cache-clear-enabled="false">
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz" datasource-name="localmysql"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.olap" datasource-name="localmysqlolap"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.tenant" datasource-name="localsqltenant"/>
    </delegator>
    <!-- May be used when you create a service that manages many data for massive imports, this for performance reason or to escape functional cases --> 
    <delegator name="default-no-eca" entity-model-reader="main" entity-group-reader="main" entity-eca-reader="main" entity-eca-enabled="false" distributed-cache-clear-enabled="false">
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz" datasource-name="localmysql"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.olap" datasource-name="localmysqlolap"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.tenant" datasource-name="localmysqltenant"/>
    </delegator>

    <!-- Be sure that your default delegator (or the one you use) uses the same datasource for test. You must run "gradlew loadAll" before running "gradlew testIntegration" -->
    <delegator name="test" entity-model-reader="main" entity-group-reader="main" entity-eca-reader="main">
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz" datasource-name="localmysql"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.olap" datasource-name="localmysqlolap"/>
        <group-map group-name="org.apache.ofbiz.tenant" datasource-name="localmysqltenant"/>
    </delegator>
```

**Error**
When I run OFBiz with this configuration I receive the following `HTTP 500` error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not get next sequenced ID for sequence name: Visit
    org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.getNextSeqId(GenericDelegator.java:2280)
    org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.getNextSeqId(GenericDelegator.java:2268)
    org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntity.setNextSeqId(GenericEntity.java:657)
    org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.createSetNextSeqId(GenericDelegator.java:771)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.stats.VisitHandler.getVisit(VisitHandler.java:187)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.stats.VisitHandler.getVisitId(VisitHandler.java:100)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doGet(ControlServlet.java:201)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.SameSiteFilter.doFilter(SameSiteFilter.java:44)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:191)
    org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlFilter.doFilter(ControlFilter.java:157)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

**Kubernetes error logs**
Using kubectl logs $POD, here is one of the errors that shows up. All of the errors are related to jdbc driver it seems.

````
2021-03-27 23:33:50,408 |OFBiz-JobPoller      |DBCPConnectionFactory         |E| null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.connection.DBCPConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBCPConnectionFactory.java:90) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.transaction.GeronimoTransactionFactory.getConnection(GeronimoTransactionFactory.java:79) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.jdbc.SQLProcessor.getConnection(SQLProcessor.java:261) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.jdbc.SQLProcessor.prepareStatement(SQLProcessor.java:367) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.datasource.GenericDAO.selectCountByCondition(GenericDAO.java:1049) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.datasource.GenericHelperDAO.findCountByCondition(GenericHelperDAO.java:157) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.findCountByCondition(GenericDelegator.java:1694) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.findCountByCondition(GenericDelegator.java:1653) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.service.job.JobManager.isAvailable(JobManager.java:154) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.service.job.JobPoller$JobManagerPoller.run(JobPoller.java:223) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]```
````

Comment: The configuration looks good to me.
OFBiz should have created the datamodel/tables in your database, can you see them?
Are there any errors in console.log/ofbiz.log regarding the database connection when you start OFBiz?
Have you checked that you database is accessible whit a database client and user/password?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

OFBiz has not created any tables in my database.

As for the errors, there are a whole list of them related to connecting to the SQL connection which I am not sure how to parse.

Comment: I have updated my post with my OFBiz Dockerfile at the start and the one of the related errors in the cloud shell terminal towards the end.

Comment: You dońt have the MySQL driver installed. Please follow the INSTALL document to get everything setup correctly.

Comment: I have tried using multiple mysql-connector-java files and none of them have worked so far. I have made the following changes to my dockerfile after changing the allowed URL headers

```WORKDIR lib

RUN wget https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/mysql%3Amysql-connector-java/8.0.23#files/mysql%2Fmysql-connector-java%2F8.0.23```

The mysql-connector-java file is in the dir /apache/lib/. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: I have added the line ```runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23'``` in build.gradle and have overcome that driver problem. Now I am running into issues connecting to the database.

Comment: I figured it out! In my preliminary SQL commands, I had kept the command specifying $users@'localhost' instead of pointing to my pods. ```kubectl logs $POD``` indicates that the pod is running OFBiz without error. Checking the MySQL database shows that the tables have populated. Despite all of this, I am still getting the same ```HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error```

Comment: I think I have it working. I had some problems with how my DNS was set up because I was working on two different OFBiz deployments and got them mixed up. I am able to see the login page but the default logins `username=admin password=ofbiz` are unavailable and I can no longer log in.

Comment: @KarlCagalawan Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround you found to your issue? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

`${ofbiz install dir}/framework/entity/lib/jdbc`; replacing the old or incorrect version of the driver there

JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J): https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Read more at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7045252#ApacheOFBizTechnicalProductionSetupGuide-DatabaseSetup